# Crear una clase c# desde un xsd

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Tengo un problema al generar  una clase desde un xsd .

el xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Library:           OASIS Universal Business Language (UBL) 2.1 OS
                     http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/
  Release Date:      04 November 2013
  Module:            xsdrt/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd
  Generated on:      2013-10-31 17:17z
  Copyright (c) OASIS Open 2013. All Rights Reserved.
-->
<xsd:schema xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
            xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
            xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
            xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig"
            targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            version="2.1">
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
                schemaLocation="https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs1-UBL-2.1/xsd/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.1.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
              schemaLocation="https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs1-UBL-2.1/xsd/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.1.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
              schemaLocation="https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs1-UBL-2.1/xsd/common/UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.1.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig" schemaLocation = "https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/common/UBL-xmldsig-core-schema-2.1.xsd" />
   <xsd:element name="Invoice" type="InvoiceType"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="InvoiceType">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:UBLVersionID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:CustomizationID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:ProfileID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:ProfileExecutionID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:ID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:CopyIndicator" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:UUID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:IssueDate" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:IssueTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:DueDate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:InvoiceTypeCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:Note" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:TaxPointDate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:TaxCurrencyCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:PricingCurrencyCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:PaymentCurrencyCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:PaymentAlternativeCurrencyCode"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:AccountingCostCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:AccountingCost" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:LineCountNumeric" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:BuyerReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:InvoicePeriod" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:OrderReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:BillingReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:DespatchDocumentReference"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:ReceiptDocumentReference"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:StatementDocumentReference"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:OriginatorDocumentReference"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:ContractDocumentReference"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:AdditionalDocumentReference"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:ProjectReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:Signature" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:AccountingSupplierParty" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:AccountingCustomerParty" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:PayeeParty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:BuyerCustomerParty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:SellerSupplierParty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:TaxRepresentativeParty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:Delivery" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:DeliveryTerms" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:PaymentMeans" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:PaymentTerms" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:PrepaidPayment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:AllowanceCharge" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:TaxExchangeRate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:PricingExchangeRate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:PaymentExchangeRate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:PaymentAlternativeExchangeRate"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:TaxTotal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:WithholdingTaxTotal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:LegalMonetaryTotal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xsd:element ref="cac:InvoiceLine" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

y el mensaje  de error que me muestra es

> Error: No se ha declarado el elemento
>   'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2:
>   '. Line : 30 Position : 11

estoy utilizando **XSD2CODE++**

Comment: disculpen  este es el xsd

Comment: la cabezera de mi xsd

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Recuerda poner tu codigo en la pregunta. Tambien el error lo tira la extension? probaste directamente tirar el xsd en una clase (es otra forma de generar la clase, sin necesidad de terceros).